# Checkbox cannot be checked by cypress because it isn't of type 'checkbox'. How can I get around this?

Tags: checkbox, cypress

I'm trying to perform cypress tests on elements that act like checkboxes, but I'm getting the following error:

> cy.check() can only be called on `:checkbox` and `:radio`

Basically, the element I'm testing behaves like a checkbox, but is a custom component. Can I use `.check()`  etc. on this component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cypress won't allow you to use `cy.check()` on any component that is not of type checkbox or radio.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check#Requirements-Icon-namequestion-circle)

In order to `check` the component, you'll probably have to use `cy.click()` on the component. The following may not be 100% correct, but it should be as simple as just swapping out `.check()` for `.click()`.

```js
// Usage of .check()
cy.get('#my-custom-checkbox').check()

// Usage of .click()
cy.get('#my-custom-checkbox').click()
```

(This may not be accurate as the component's clickable element may be a child or sibling of what you believe is the checkbox - it may take some experimentation to find the correct element to click)